# Change Ctrl-Ins to Ctrl-C in keydown handler

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a 3rd party control (DevExpress `TcxVirtualTreeList`) that hates receiving the <kbd>Ins</kbd> keypress (access violations) and it processes the old-fashioned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Ins</kbd> (copy to clipboard) as <kbd>Ins</kbd> as well.

So I want to change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Ins</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> in its OnKeyDown handler:

```
 if (Key=VK_INSERT) and (Shift=[]) then              // Insert
 begin  
    // Handle insert ourselves
    ...
    Key := 0;
 end
 else if (Key=VK_INSERT) and (Shift=[ssCtrl]) then   // Ctrl-Ins
 begin
    Key := 67; // 'C'   
 end
```

But this does not work. The selected text (in an inner editor of the `TcxVirtualTreeList`) does not copy to the clipboard as does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.

What am I doing wrong and how to get the desired result?

- I have verified that C is indeed 67 (BTW Is VK_C defined in any unit?)
- There is a OnKeydown handler on the Form with `KeyPreview=false` that handles <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>. Disabling that handler made no difference (as expected).

**[Edited test case with ordinary TEdit]**
Sorry, I'm confusing things by mentioning that it's a DevEx control. That has nothing to do with the issue.

I managed to test it in a small app with a TEdit, the other way around (from Form to Edit) with `Form.KeyPreview=true`:

```
procedure TFrmChangeKeyInDown.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
   if (Key=VK_INSERT) and (Shift=[]) then
   begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('FormKeyDown: Ins detected');
   end
   else if (Key=VK_INSERT) and (Shift=[ssCtrl]) then
   begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('FormKeyDown: Ctrl-Ins detected, changing to Ctrl-C');
      Key := 67;
   end;
end;

procedure TFrmChangeKeyInDown.EditKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
   if (Key=VK_INSERT) and (Shift=[]) then
   begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('EditKeyDown: Ins detected');
   end
   else if (Key=VK_INSERT) and (Shift=[ssCtrl]) then
   begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('EditKeyDown: Ctrl-Ins detected');
   end
   else if (Key=67) and (Shift=[ssCtrl]) then
   begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('EditKeyDown: Ctrl-C detected');
   end;
end;
```

Type something in the edit control, select a word, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Ins</kbd>, the memo shows:

```
FormKeyDown: Ctrl-Ins detected, changing to Ctrl-C
EditKeyDown: Ctrl-C detected
```

**but the contents of my clipboard buffer are now NOT that word**. Do this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and it works fine.

Comment: That seems a little odd. Surely somebody else would have noticed. What to devExpress say? I'd expect them to fix such egregious bugs. Also, I guess you have the source code so you could readily fix it yourself.

Comment: This is subtle. I'm actually talking about a TcxVirtualTreeList cast to their TcxScheduler.GanttView.TreeBrowser where you are not supposed to have OptionsData.Inserting := true. I do set that, because I want other features (The NavBar with the Insert key), and the consequence is that I have to handle some things like blocking the Ins, and blocking automatic append when you move down past the last row. I don't blame them for the fact that their control no longer seems to listen to the old fashioned Ctrl-Ins. I'm an old fashioned user who has that combination grown into my fingers.

Comment: @david Your suggestion about diving into their source code is welcome though. Let's see what that turns up.

Comment: Oh you are absolutely right to want to deal with this bogus handling of standard shortcuts. I'm not disagreeing with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is an acceptable solution, but if you add

```
Edit.CopyToClipboard;
```

to the EditKeyDown handler, just after (or instead of) the

```
    Memo1.Lines.Add('EditKeyDown: Ctrl+C detected');
```

then it'll copy the text to the clipboard, just as if you had pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> yourself. If there isn't a CopyToClipboard on the TreeList control you are using, then you can use the

```
Clipboard.AsText:=<Text to copy to clipboard>
```

if you can access the currently selected text from the ListView.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> handling is not done by VCL but by Windows, AFAIK, *so you can't just "feed" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> into a VCL control and expect it to perform clipboard operations*.

Comment: I have not tried this yet, but it should be the way to go. You're right of course with that last remark, I have edited it for emphasis.

Comment: Since I'm using a DevEx TcxVirtualTreeList my code in its OnKeyDown handler is now (if (Key=VK_INSERT) and (Shift=[ssCtrl])): *if FTreeList.InplaceEditor is TcxCustomTextEdit then
         Clipboard.AsText := TcxCustomTextEdit(FTreeList.InplaceEditor).SelText;*

Comment: @JanDoggen: I would recommend that you use (Shift*[ssShift,ssAlt,ssCtrl]=[ssCtrl]) to check if Ctrl is pressed, as TShiftState potentially can contain more information than simply the currently pressed shift states of the various shift keys...